# how set UIView and Image size after selecting size of image and view as paper size in inches

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I*strong text* am making passport app in which i am getting image size for example 2x2 inches and than paper size for example 8x11 inches(A4-size). than how can i show all images in one view with those sized. i resize the image , set collection view in UIView and give count by dividing paper_size/image_size. but in some case paper_size become more bigger than device with or height. also i want to stick the collection view (non-scrollable) so that i can pass the screenshot for printing

Answer (score 1):

class GridLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

```
var itemSpacing: CGFloat = 5
var rowSpacing: CGFloat = 5

private var itemSize: CGSize!
private var numberOfRows: Int!
private var numberOfColumns: Int!

override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()

    let count = collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

    numberOfColumns = Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(count))))
    numberOfRows = Int(ceil(Double(count) / Double(numberOfColumns)))

    let width = (collectionView!.bounds.width - (itemSpacing * CGFloat(numberOfColumns - 1))) / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
    let height = (collectionView!.bounds.height - (rowSpacing * CGFloat(numberOfRows - 1))) / CGFloat(numberOfRows)
    itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return collectionView!.bounds.size
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

    attributes.center = centerForItem(at: indexPath)
    attributes.size = itemSize

    return attributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    return (0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)).map { IndexPath(item: $0, section: 0) }
        .flatMap { layoutAttributesForItem(at: $0) }
}

private func centerForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGPoint {

    let row = indexPath.item / numberOfColumns
    let col = indexPath.item - row * numberOfColumns

    return CGPoint(x: CGFloat(col) * (itemSize.width + itemSpacing) + itemSize.width / 2,
                   y: CGFloat(row) * (itemSize.height + rowSpacing) + itemSize.height / 2)
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}